# Is there a tool like fiddler that supports http2?

Tags: performance, fiddler, http2

I tend to user fiddler for its autoresponder (testing how latency or invalid responses will impact overall page loads) and only just now realized that http2 is not supported, all site default to http1/1 when loading pages along with fiddler! Any recommendations of replacement tool would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

### Mitmproxy

I have not tried the http/2 capability myself but based on the official documentation [mitmproxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-protocols/) is capable of intercepting HTTP/2 traffic.

Mitmproxy is Python based. On Windows you can use the two variants `mitmweb` (starts a web server as UI that can be opened in a web browser) and `mitmdump` (command-line no GUI).

### Charles Proxy

Also [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com) has according to it's docs HTTP/2 support.

Charles Proxy is Java based

### Burp Suite

[Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) (AFAIR Java based) claims to have HTTP/2 support

Answer (score 1):

The paid version of Fiddler - [Fiddler Everywhere](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler-everywhere) supports HTTP/2 in its current version. Capturing traffic, using the composer and the rules builder (autoresponder) all work the HTTP/2 protocol if you enable it in the app's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but if you look something inside the .NET ecosystem, [fluxzy](https://github.com/haga-rak/fluxzy.core) can do the job. It's both an OSS proxy engine usable with .NET and an HTTP Debugger that supports HTTP/2.